# Handle share intent resultcode in Android

Tags: android, share, onactivityresult

Is there a way to handle resultcode for share intents?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.it");

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1285);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1285) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(resultCode));
    }
}
```

I tried with facebook. I can share the url fine but in both cases (share, cancel) the resultCode return 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)`

Comment: It's the same since it return always 0 in both case!

Answer (score 0):

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that
>   are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as
>   ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you
>   expect. For example, if the activity you are launching uses the
>   singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will
>   immediately receive a cancel result.

Referance: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29